# Evaluating $ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{x^{2}} $ using Riemann sums only.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How does one evaluate the following Riemann integral by using Riemann sums only?
$$
\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{x^{2}}.
$$

Comment: What are your attempts? What, exactly, is your definition?

Comment: Usually, I would go with $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=an}^{bn}{\frac{1}{(\frac{k}{n})^2}}$ . But here, if I do this, the sum diverges.

Comment: Try using $c_i=\sqrt{x_{i-1}x_{i}}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compute the integral as the limit of a Riemann sum:

$$S_n =\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}k\right)^{-2}.$$

We have

$$\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}k\right)^{-1}\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}(k+1)\right)^{-1} \leqslant S_n \\ \leqslant \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}k\right)^{-1}\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}(k-1)\right)^{-1},$$

and decomposing into partial fractions,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left\{\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}k\right)^{-1}-\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}(k+1)\right)^{-1}\right\} \leqslant S_n \\\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n \left\{\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}(k-1)\right)^{-1}-\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}k\right)^{-1}\right\}. $$

The sums are telescoping. Hence,

$$\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}\right)^{-1}-\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n}(n+1)\right)^{-1} \leqslant S_n \leqslant a^{-1} - b^{-1}.$$

By the squeeze theorem, we get the value of the integral as

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n = a^{-1} - b^{-1}.$$